# how to give 'yes' for series of applications via batchfile?

Tags: batch-file

I need to run an application via batch file.
this application runs 6 other applications one by one.
I need to give Yes for all those automatically.
how can I do that?

Comment: Are these `yes`es popup windows or needed to be written in the console?

Comment: `echo Yes|command` (6×)?

Comment: Please do *not* post [the same question](http://superuser.com/questions/1055600/how-to-give-yes-while-running-an-application-via-batchfile) multiple times!

Answer (score 1):

See [yes](http://linux.die.net/man/1/yes). Basically you will call your jobs by piping output of yes to these commands. Like

```
> yes | somecommand
```